# Client-Server: How to handle incoming server response(s) (while loop) in multi-threads in client? [C Program]

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, multiprocessing, pthreads

So I have a server that sends a response object in a while loop.

- The while loop continues until x number of response objects is sent to the client.

I want to handle the incoming requests in threads (so the client is able to still do other stuff i.e. enter user inputs.)

**Current approach: In client I have a 'thread pool' that is randomly creating threads and 
`handleNextReceiveClient` will handle incoming request.**

```
// client

  int num_handler_threads = 100;  // random number (knowing responses will be less than 100 at any time.)

        int thr_id[num_handler_threads]; /* thread IDs  */

        /* create the request-handling threads */
        for (i = 0; i < num_handler_threads; i++)
        {
            //TO DO
            // CREATE THREADS - Threads to call handleNextReceiveClient() function
            pthread_t t;
            pthread_attr_t attr;
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            pthread_create(&t, &attr, (void *)(void *)handleNextReceiveClient, (void *)&data1);
        }
```

**Thread function:**

```
void handleNextReceiveClient(void *ptr)
{

    thdata *data;
    data = (thdata *)ptr; /* type cast to a pointer to thdata */

    if (recv(data->sockfd, &response, sizeof(response_t), 0))
    {

       // Display response  
       // exit(0); // exit out of THREAD so I am able to use the client while server sends next reponse object in a few seconds.x`  

   }
    else
    {

        exit(0);
    }

    printf("\n break.....\n");
}
```

**Server sending response in a while loop**

```
// server
while(numberOfResponseObjects != total) {

    send(response, fdNew); // send a reponse. 
    sleep(3); // wait few seconds before sending next response object to client.

}
```

**PROBLEM: What happends**: As soon as the server sends the first response to client thread, it displays as expected but doesn't end the thread and then the next response is displayed until all responses are displayed (WITHOUT) client being able to do anything else in between, only after until all response objects from the server are displayed client is free to do other stuff...

**What is wrong with my approach? ideas?**

Comment: Do you use datagrams (UDP) or a stream (TCP)? A thread pool might be useful if processing the response must be done while receiving the next response. Otherwise one thread for the *other stuff* and one  for receiving and processing the responses would be sufficient. If you really need parallel processing of the responses: Don't use multiple threads that read from the same file descriptor. I suggest to use one thread that reads from the fd until it has received a complete response and pass the response to a thread for processing. If you use a stream you should also handle partial reads.

Comment: I am using: socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) i.e. TCP streaming. The responses are incoming in order and I'd like to process one after the other (not parallel). Currently, I am thinking with the above approach is only one thread handling all the responses (note: cause server is sending them fast one after other in while loop)? ...is it hard to tell with limited code?

Comment: `recv()` can return (i) a positive value, indicating success; (ii) zero, indicating end of stream; (iii) a negative value, indicating an error. It is therefore totally incorrect to merely test the result for non-zero. It is also hard to see why you think you need multiple receiving threads for a single socket.

Comment: @Shaz Please [edit] your question and include all additional information there. You don't need more than one thread for receiving and processing the responses if you want to do it in order one after the other. If you don't enable non-blocking mode, the `send` operation in your server will block automatically if the client doesn't `recv` the data fast enough. To get useful recommendations you should add a rough description of your communication protocol including the size of the data and how you identify the start of a new response.

Comment: Of course your server must be able to handle several clients either by using a separate thread or process per connection or by using `select` and non-blocking operations. On both ends your code must be able to handle partial reads, e.g. only half of the response with the rest following later.